# IE 8 div and css cursor

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In example bellow when you hover on icons cursor should be changed to different. It works except of IE 8. On IE 8 these icons turned to be unclikable, i.e. not only cursor are not changed, but also Jquery click event does not fire. Consider how the following html code works at FF, IE7 and eventually at IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>CSS IE 8 cursor test</title>
     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .icon-button {
            float: left; 
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .ui-icon { width: 15px; height: 10px; background-image: url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/replies-off.png); }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="icon-button ui-icon"></div>
   <div>Sample Text</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

What migth be the root of problem? What could be possible workarrounds? 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. Changing DOCTYPE is not really possible.
Also if I remove  *float: left* on this example it seems like "fixed", but when I remove it on a website, besides broken design, it does not help also.

Comment: This works too: `cursor: pointer !important;` for ie8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 doesn't like empty `div`s. Putting a blank `<img/>` with a transparent pixel inside the div seems to fix it.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/asiju (Editable via http://jsbin.com/asiju/edit)

HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>CSS IE 8 cursor test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .icon-button { float: left; cursor: pointer; }
      .ui-icon { width: 15px; height: 10px; background-image: url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/replies-off.png); }
      .dummy-image { width: 15px; height: 10px; vertical-align: top; border: none; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="icon-button ui-icon"><img class="dummy-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJH/AP///wAAAMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAABAAEAQAICVAEAOw=="/></div>
    <div>Sample Text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! I have applied it, seems to be fixed. But did you notice that border of IMG actually doesn't disappear on IE8?

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer to include a 1x1 transparent pixel in the image tag. That gets rid of the border: http://jsbin.com/asiju

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any hack to beat it. But, if smth could be clicked it should be in `a` tag, so insert `a` and maybe `display:block`. `href` could be `=#`. That solution seems to be semantic and good for me :)

Comment: Thank you, but nope, I've just tried to substitute div to a in my example:
  <a class="icon-button ui-icon" href="#"></a> - it did not help...

Comment: I mean, insert `a` to `div`, default `a` cursor is pointer :)

Comment: I agree with Rinz. It's probably best to use a link with an image (`<a><img/></a>`), just like Stack Overflow does, or at least use a button (`<button></button>`) with a background-image. It's more semantic.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<a href="whatever.php">
<div class="BG IMAGE" style="cursor:The one you want"></div>
</a>
```

I use it myself and it works fine.

Comment: you can't put a div inside an a

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `float:left` and the css class looks like below.

```
.icon-button { cursor: pointer; }
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me in IE8, super simple

```
cursor: pointer !important;
```